# How can i call a function of user control in [WebMethod]?

Tags: jquery, user-controls

Iam having a USercontrol UMessages.ascx where i have function to show message as

```
    function ShowSuccess(Message) {
            alert(" ShowSuccess");
            $(".litMessage").text(Message);
            $(".MessageBox").class("success");
            $(".MessageBox").show();
        }
```

Iam having Default.aspx page where iam using Ajax call to update value and after updation i just wanted to show Message which is in User Control.i.e., ShowSuccess

How i can use this ShowSuccess in Jquery or in WebMethod..?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use webmethod

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 function ShowSuccess(Message) {
        alert(" ShowSuccess");
        $(".litMessage").text(Message);
        $(".MessageBox").class("success");
        $(".MessageBox").show();
    }
```

and in aspx page write this jquery function

```
function callPageMthodWithjQueryAjax() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/Default.aspx/ShowSuccess',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ argument: argument }),
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                jQuery('#result').html(data.d);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var jsonError = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                alert(jsonError.Message);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: U mean you want to write webmethod for that function?? where iam using selectors